# Node.js Hmac SHA256 base64 of string

Tags: java, android, node.js

I'm making an app in java and a server with node and as an authentication method I would like to compare two strings.

In java i'm doing this:

```
try {
    String secret = "secret";
    String message = "Message";

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

    String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
    System.out.println(hash);
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

But I'm still pretty new to node.js and I'm trying to figure out how to do the same there. This is what I've got:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var sha256 = crypto.createHash('HMAC-SHA256').update('Message').digest("base64");
```

How can I make them do the same? I'm still missing the salt in node.js. 
Suggestions?

**EDIT:**
The answer below helped me find the solution. If other android users has this problem then this code worked for me:

```
try {
    String secret = "secret";
    String message = "Message";

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    byte[] s53 = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    String hash = Base64.encodeToString(s53, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.e("beadict", hash);
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

And this in node:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', "secret").update("Message").digest('base64');
```

Comment: One nit to pick - I recommend that you specify the character encoding in the Java `getBytes()` calls. While the Android default is UTF-8 (see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset() ) it doesn't hurt to be explicit, especially if the hash is to be generated on different machines. That said, I am not 100% sure what the node equivalent/default is. Point being, if the String -> byte[] encodings do not match, neither will the resulting hashes.

Comment: Thanks @just_user your question and solution helped me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use a HMAC then you need to use the method `crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key)`.

> I'm still missing the salt in node.js

It seems that you do not use the salt in your Java code...

Answer (score 44):

You can use this line:

```
let test = crypto.createHmac('sha256', "key").update("message").digest("base64");
```

Convert to base64 last.

Comment: This was the simplest answer for me. I appreciate that you used the .update("json") over .update("message"). The only difference for me was I did .digest("hex") for my application.